# Will Fakes be made available on versions of Visual Studio other than 'Ultimate' as Moles is?

Tags: visual-studio, moles, microsoft-fakes

Does anyone know if there are any intentions to make Fakes available on releases of Visual Studio lower than Ultimate?

Fakes seems to be billed as replacing Moles but if it will only work in Ultimate, most Moles users won't have access to it.

Comment: They have not made any such intentions public, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Fakes are in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate only, as of posting this answer. This may change in future versions and updates.

Comment: Argh. I have extensive testing built on Pex and Moles in VS 2010. I guess I either rip it out or stay with 2010. What a pity. [No, I can't afford the Ultimate version: too expensive for an academic!]

Comment: Converting to fakes is very easy. The syntax has changed very little.

Comment: It looks it, which makes moving away from it all the more painful!